# How to import a csv file that matches certain formation?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a function which produces a dictionary in this formation:

```
D1 = {
    'A': [1, 5, 9],
    'B': [2, 6, 10],
    'C': [3, 7, 11],
    'D': [4, 8, 12],
}
```

Then I have a .csv file look like this

```
A  B  C  D
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

Then I import this .csv file by using (I am using pandas)

```
D1_T = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', index_col=None, squeeze=True).to_dict()
```

Then I print out:

```
print("Return Value : %d" %  operator.eq(D1, D1_T))
```

to determine whether those two `dict`s are the same or not.

However, the answer is `0`.

Did I define my .csv file wrong or I import it wrong? I wish to import or define the .csv file correctly so it matches with `D1` above.

Comment: Try `D1_T = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', index_col=None, squeeze=True).to_dict(orient='list')` and try again...

Comment: Thanks! that works!